# jQuery Animation Not Going Back Down

Tags: jquery

I got no idea what is wrong, please help.

The jQuery animation wont go back down.

Link: http://extreme-network.tk/

Code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $('#footer').hover(function () {
         $(this).stop().animate({
             top: "444px"
         }, 500);
     }, function () {
         var width = $(this).height() - 32;
         $(this).stop().animate({
             bottom: -height
         }, 500);
   });
 });
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined extreme-network.tk/:1`

Comment: `var width = $(this).height() -32;` this should have probably been `var height`

Comment: Post your code here, and create a JSFiddle demo.

Comment: FSFiddle won't work with the code, can't you view the source of the webpage?

Comment: Can't you just post your code here? And no, asking someone to "Fix it for me" doesn't work on SO, especially when nobody really knows what `it` is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cbFtB/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `var width = $(this).height() -32;` I guess you want `var height = $(this).height() - 32;`

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#footer').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({top:"444px"},500);     
    },function () {
        var height = $(this).height() -32;
        $(this).stop().animate({bottom: - height  },500);     
    });
});
```

Also your code can be simplified:

```
$('#footer').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({top:"440px"}, 500);     
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({top: "494px" },500);     
});
```

---

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UptTZ/show/) **|**
[**JSFIDDLE CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UptTZ/)

Comment: The second one doesn't work.

Comment: @CurtisSalter It's the same code but in the seccond link the iframe is too little to see the div. This is the reason for that I've posted the first link.